# Deformation equivalence of $\mathbb{P}^n$ bundles over $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbf{a}=(a_0,\cdots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ be an array of integers, let $\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{a})=\oplus_{i=0}^n\mathcal{O}(a_i)$ be the vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$, and let $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{a}))$ be its projectivization. We know that $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{a}))$ and $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{b}))$ are isomorphic iff $\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}=(k,\cdots,k)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For $n\geq2$, is there an explicit numerical criterion telling whether $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{a}))$ and $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{b}))$ are deformation equivalent?

(In case $n=1$, we know Hirzebruch surfaces are deformation equivalent iff $a_1-a_0\equiv b_1-b_0$ mod $2$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The projective bundles $\mathbb{P}(a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(b)$ are deformation equivalent if and only if
$$
\sum a_i \equiv \sum b_i \bmod n + 1.
$$
To show this it is enough to check that $\mathbb{P}(a)$ is deformation equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(a')$, where
$$
a' = (a_0 - 1, a_1 + 1, a_2, \dots, a_n).
$$
For this assume that $a_0 \le a_1$. Then there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}(a_0 - 1) \to \mathcal{O}(a_0) \oplus \mathcal{O}(a_1) \to \mathcal{O}(a_1 + 1) \to 0,
$$
hence there is a deformation equivalence between vector bundles
$$
\mathcal{O}(a_0 - 1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(a_1 + 1)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathcal{O}(a_0) \oplus \mathcal{O}(a_1)
$$
that corresponds to deformation to zero of the extension class of the above exact sequence. Taking the sum with the other line bundles and passing to projectivizations, one obtains the required deformation equivalence for projective bundles.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but why is the criterion necessary? (You checked sufficiency.)

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn: If $\mathbb{P}(a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(b)$ are deformation equivalent, there is an isomorphism between their Picard group which preserves the degree on the fibers. In particular, denoting by $p,q$ the projections to $\mathbb{P}^1$, we have an isomorphism $p_*\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(a)}(1)\cong q_*\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(b)}(1)\otimes \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(c)$ for some $c\in\Bbb{Z}$. Taking determinants gives $\sum a_i=\sum b_j+(n+1)c$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: another argument uses intersection theory. The class $f$ of a fiber of the morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$ is canonically defined by the condition $f^2 = 0$. Then the class $h$ of a relative hyperplane is defined by the condition $h^n\cdot f = 1$ uniquely, up to adding multiples of $f$. It follows that $h^{n+1} = \sum a_i$ is defined uniquely modulo $n + 1$. All these considerations are deformation equivalent.